# Java REST - Path Variable causes 404 when over value 9

Tags: java, rest

I am extremely desperate and tired.
My problem is the following:
I have created a REST-Service for a project I am working on for school. There I have a few requests which interact with my db based upon a Path Variable. The catch is, that I cannot request something over the value of 9. To further illustrate, what I mean, I have copied the following snippet:

```
@GET
@Path("/Child/{Child: \\d+}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public Response Child(@PathParam ("Child")int child) throws IOException{
    DAO dao = new DAO();
    List<Child> Child;
    try{
        Child = dao.Child(child);
        ResponseBuilder rb = Response.ok();
        rb.entity(new GenericEntity<List<Child>>(Child) {});

        return rb.build();

    }catch(Exception e){
        ResponseBuilder rp = Response.status(404);
        return rp.build();
    }

}
```

Instead of returning the Child object with the matching index (which exists, I have checked multiple times to see, if I am really not just overlooking the obvious), it returns a 404 code. It doesn't even seem to catch the exception because I have changed the response code and it still returned the same result. I have also tried to customize the variable (as seen above with \d+, there have been various other expressions, but none of them worked either). I have searched the web for answers, but none of the answers found were able to help me. If more information is needed, I am more than happy to provide it.

Comment: just to be clear if id is over 9 it returns 404. isn't it ?

Comment: If you remove the space after the colon in the param does anything change? Also, which container and JAXRS library is this (assuming that's what you are using?

Comment: Try to replace your regex `\\d+` by `[0-9]+`, just in case.

Comment: If there was any error in try block you will end up with 404 according to your code. So try printing the Exception stack trace and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you want any digit in path variable and it can be greater than 9 as well. Try  below. Also in case of non-digit value, below will give 404 so you dont need To handle it in your method.

```
    @GET
    @Path("/Child/{Child:[0-9]+}")
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    public Response Child(@PathParam("Child") int child) throws IOException {
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
```

Comment: I just got up and I tried the expression, that you used and it worked! So thank you for your help :D I feel pretty stupid now. Guess I should've gone to bed earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is somewhere else. This works like a champ for me:

```
@Path("/server/{server: \\d+}")
public class Restful {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response getText(@PathParam("server") int pid) {
        return Response.status(200).build();
    }
}
```

Servlet mapping:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Url used:

```
http://localhost:8080/restfulServer/rest/server/200
```

on Tomcat 8.5 and jersey